# Acceder a sub ítem de otro sub item

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un `array` con sub ítem anidado:

```
let datos = [
    
    Perfil: {
        nombre: "",
        URL: ""
    },

    ubicacion: {
    
        YouTube: {
            nombre: "",
            URL: ""
        },
        
        Facebook: {
            nombre: "",
            URL: ""
        },
    
    }

];
```

Accedo fácilmente a `Perfil` así:

```
<a href="${item["Perfil"].URL}">${item["Perfil"].nombre}</a>
```

Pero no encuentro cómo acceder a la propiedad `nombre` de `ubicacion`  iterando de la misma forma

Éste es mi código:

```
let tarjeta [];

datos.forEach( (item) => {

    document.getElementById("recomendados").innerHTML = `
  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="${item["Perfil"].URL}">${item["Perfil"].nombre}</a></li>
    </ul>

`;

});
```

Comment: Sería interesante que pongas cómo estás tratando de acceder al campo ubicacion

Comment: Es de la misma forma como tengo en la etiqueta `a` en el ejemplo

Comment: La declaración de `datos` es incorrecta, parece que le faltan llaves

Comment: @PabloLozano tal cual como está me funciona bien. El problema era solo el sub item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás omitiendo un nivel en tu anidación 'Facebook'/'YouTube' (según la estructura planteada)

```
<li><a href="${item["ubicacion"]["Facebook"].URL}">${item["ubicacion"]["Facebook"].nombre}</a></li>
```

Comment: No me funciona de esa manera, causa un error y no muestra nada de la lista

Comment: OK. Me funciona ahora que a toda la lista le modifique con los mismos items de ubicación

Comment: Es importante agregar una explicación de lo que hace el código.

Answer (score 1):

Solo añadí unas llaves al `json`.

***Json***

```
let datos = [
    {//añadi llaves
        Perfil: {
            nombre: "LINK",
            URL: "http://google.com"
        },

        ubicacion: {
            YouTube: {
                nombre: "",
                URL: ""
            },

            Facebook: {
                nombre: "",
                URL: ""
            },
        }
    }
];
```

***JS***

```
let tarjeta = [];


datos.forEach((item) => {

    document.getElementById("recomendados").innerHTML = `
  
    <ul>
       <li><a href=${item.Perfil.URL}>${item.Perfil.nombre}</a></li>
    </ul>

    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="${item["Perfil"].URL}">${item["Perfil"].nombre}</a></li>
    </ul>
`;    
});
```

Funciona de las 2 formas

***HTML***

```
<div id="recomendados" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu ingresas a los valores de la clave `URL` y `nombre` de la clave `Perfil` así:

```
<a href="${item["Perfil"].URL}">${item["Perfil"].nombre}</a>
```

Pues entonces podrías hacer lo mismo para los demás, ingresas a los valores de las claves `YouTube` y `Facebook` de la clave `ubicacion`, y de esas claves, ingresar a los valores de las claves `nombre` y `URL` de cada una de ellas, al igual que hacías anteriormente, así:

```
<li><a href="${item['ubicacion']['YouTube'].URL}">${item['ubicacion']['YouTube'].nombre}</a></li>
<li><a href="${item['ubicacion']['Facebook'].URL}">${item['ubicacion']['Facebook'].nombre}</a></li>
```

Para que lo entiendas mejor, es como seguir una secuencia, aquí, de los `item`, ingreso a la clave `ubicacion`, y de esa clave, ingreso a la clave `Facebook` y `YouTube`, y de esas claves, ingreso a la clave `nombre` y `URL`, obteniendo los valores de esos dos.

---

Te doy un ejemplo reproducible:

```js
let datos = [
  {
    Perfil: {
      nombre: 'ejemplo1',
      URL: 'www.ejemplo.com',
    },
    ubicacion: {
      YouTube: {
        nombre: 'ejemplo2',
        URL: 'www.youtube.com',
      },
      Facebook: {
        nombre: 'ejemplo3',
        URL: 'www.facebook.com',
      },
    },
  },
];

datos.forEach((item) => {
  document.getElementById('recomendados').innerHTML = `
    <li><a href="${item['Perfil'].URL}">${item['Perfil'].nombre}</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="${item['ubicacion']['YouTube'].URL}">${item['ubicacion']['YouTube'].nombre}</a></li>
      <li><a href="${item['ubicacion']['Facebook'].URL}">${item['ubicacion']['Facebook'].nombre}</a></li>
    </ul>
  `;
});
```

```html
<div id="recomendados"></div>
```